# Xtext create nested scopes

Tags: scope, xtext

My xtext grammar constrains a hierarchical structure. When the scope of an element in the hierarchical needs to be computed the following must be done:

- get a list of element with the type A
- get a list of element with the type B

add the two list to the scope. Repeat the for the parent element and add the parents scope to the current scope.

I use

```
scope_a =  Scopes.scopeFor(list_a)
scope_b =  Scopes.scopeFor(list_b, scope_a)
```

but get stuck when adding the parents scope to `scope_b` to create the final scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `scopeFor` methods are just helpers. have a look at their code. they call

```
org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.Scopes.scopeFor(Iterable<? extends T>, Function<T, QualifiedName>, IScope)
```

which allows to pass a parent scope

Comment: `scopeFor` use the class `SimpleScope` does there exist a scope class what will be better suited?

Comment: Hav a look. Your requirements are vague. What’s bad about simplescope

Comment: Simplescope work perfectly. I wonder about efficiency. Does the upper scope being build each time the scope of an element in the current level needs to be determined?

Comment: you should always measure, not speculate

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a better method than the one I am using. With SimpleScope the scoping work.